# How to get the link of all categories

Tags: categories, links

I have this code:

```
<div class="widget-title"><h2><?php echo esc_attr(of_get_option('carousel_post_title'));?></h2></div>
```

So in my home-page.php i GET the categories, how it is possible while i get the categories, to get also the link of the categories in self??

my page php code is :

```
<div class="carousel_post_home_wrapper">
<div class="row carousel_post_home">
  <div class="twelve columns carousel_header_wrapper">
 <div class="widget-title"><h2><?php echo esc_attr(of_get_option('carousel_post_title'));?></h2></div> 

 <div class="owl_carousel carousel_header">


       <?php
  $category_carousel_post="";
  $number_of_carousel= of_get_option('number_carousel');
  $category_carousel= of_get_option('carousel_post');
  if (of_get_option('number_offset_carousel_post')){$number_offset_carousel_post = of_get_option('number_offset_carousel_post');}else{$number_offset_carousel_post = 0;}

  if(!empty($category_carousel)) {

  foreach($category_carousel as $key=>$value) { if($value == 1) { $category_carousel_post[] = $key; } } 
  }


  $post_array_carousel = array(
            'showposts' => $number_of_carousel,
            'category__in' => $category_carousel_post,
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
      'offset' => $number_offset_carousel_post
        );  
        $jellywp_widget_carousel = new WP_Query($post_array_carousel);
    $i=0;
     while ($jellywp_widget_carousel->have_posts()) {
            $jellywp_widget_carousel->the_post();
      $i++;
      $post_id = get_the_ID();
      //get all post categories
            $categories = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
```

What i mean is every time i have the category title i want also this title have a link and go to mypage.com/category/nameofthecategory

Sorry about my English, if you need further explanation tell me please..

Answer (score 0):

Well, WordPress has some integrated functions for that. Two of those would be `get_category_by_slug` ([Codex link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug)) or `get_category_link` ([Codex link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)).

I am not sure what `of_get_option()` returns, but those two might help you.

Comment: Forgot to mention that i tried these on WordPress codex.I Didn't worked it out how to place my php so any time the category has a link also, so in click, visitor can see all the category.php //

Comment: The theme is using a page builder, so you manage what category will be visible in the home-page.php and pull any time what category you "tick", so, the problem is, i want to add a code, that will pull the link of the category together with the title of the category(probably title is already get) the question is: that how i will link that title to the category ant time, is it function should i edit any code in my functions.php, should i code my home-pahe.php ???I think is too complicated :(

Comment: Well, it´s surely possible. But you need to have a good knowledge of how the theme works, where and how those links are generated, if you can overwrite those functions etc. I am sorry, but we need more information to help you on this. Like: "I got this function to output category links and I tried this and that code and it won´t work."